# Zeppelin error org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, aws-glue

I'm using Zeppelin in local connected to an Dev AWS Glue EndPoint. Until two weeks ago all worked fine, but now I'm getting this error:

> org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException   at
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
>     at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
>     at
>   org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:266)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:373)
>     at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:97)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:406)
>     at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)  at
>   org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:329)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The spark interpreter is configured as AWS tells:

[image]

As I know the problem is that zeppelin can't connect to spark interpreter. What I'm missing?
Many thanks.

Comment: Did you try to restart the spark interpreter?

Comment: Have you searched [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=262) for similar questions?

Comment: Yes, I restarted a lot of times. Finally, yesterday I solved this. It seems like AWS has made some updates in their End Points and now it works with the 0.8.0 zeppelin version.